# Transform an XSLT file with paramenter into another XSLT file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

Here I have an XSLT file, with some XPath value come from outside. For example, I have 1 parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="companyName" select="''"/>
```

And an element:

```
    <xsl:element name="Promotions">
        <xsl:attribute name="CompanyName">
            <xsl:value-of select="$companyName"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
```

Now, when I enter value `abc` for `companyName`, I want to generate a new XSL file, which has

```
<xsl:attribute name="CompanyName">abc</xsl:attribute>
```

How could I do that? Please help me. Thank you so much.

P/s: I use Java.

*Edited!***

In short, here is what I want:

In source file:

```
<xsl:param name="companyName" select="''"/>
<xsl:template name="start">
    <xsl:element name="Promotions">
        <xsl:attribute name="CompanyName">
            <xsl:value-of select="$companyName"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

When I enter `abc` as a value for `CompanyName`, `myStart` for `start` in output file:

```
<xsl:template match="myStart">
    <xsl:element name="Promotions">
        <xsl:attribute name="CompanyName">abc</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which part of the problem are you finding difficult? Generating XSLT is just like generating any other XML document. You might like to read up about the xsl:namespace-alias declaration, if only because examples of xsl:namespace-alias are usually concerned with generating stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is the best way to do this?  XSLT + XSLT = new XSLT, using transformer?

Comment: Sorry, I can't design a program for you with only one line of information about the requirements.

Comment: I've edited my question. Is that enough for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSLT stylesheet is an XML document, and this is no different from any other problem involving transforming XML into XML.  In this case you appear to want to keep most of your input file (i.e. the initial stylesheet) the same but replace any `<xsl:value-of select="$companyName" />` with a fixed value.  This can be accomplished with the usual approach based on an "identity template" to copy all the input to the output unchanged except when overridden by more specific templates.  The "more specific template" in this case is the one matching that particular `value-of` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- treat whitespace the same as an XSLT processor would - ignore text nodes
       containing only whitespace, except within xsl:text -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:preserve-space elements="xsl:text" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- the parameter you describe in the question -->
  <xsl:param name="companyName" select="''"/>

  <!-- the identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- handling for the specific value-of element -->
  <xsl:template match="xsl:value-of[@select = '$companyName']">
    <xsl:value-of select="$companyName" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `match` expression for that last template is looking for the string consisting of a dollar sign followed by `companyName`, not the value of the parameter in this stylesheet, whereas the `select` actually inserts the parameter value as a text node.

However, it may be more robust if instead of trying to replace the places where the parameter value is *used* in the original stylesheet (for example the above would miss anywhere where the value is used in a more complex expression such as `concat($companyName, ' (company)')`), you simply re-write the parameter's *definition* as a `variable`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <!-- the parameter you describe in the question -->
  <xsl:param name="companyName" select="''"/>

  <!-- the identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- handling for the specific param element -->
  <xsl:template match="/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:param[@name = 'companyName']">
    <xsl:element name="xsl:variable">
      <xsl:attribute name="name">companyName</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="$companyName" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would convert an input stylesheet such as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="companyName" select="''" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Promotions">
      <xsl:attribute name="CompanyName">
        <xsl:value-of select="$companyName"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

into

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="companyName">abc</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Promotions">
      <xsl:attribute name="CompanyName">
        <xsl:value-of select="$companyName"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives exactly the same behaviour but with the `companyName` now hard-coded rather than parameterized.  I went for generating `<xsl:variable name="...">value</xsl:variable>` instead of `<xsl:variable name="..." select="'value'" />` to allow for the possibility that the `value` could contain a single quote character (e.g. "Sainsbury's") - using text content is usually considered less efficient as it will generate an extra node but it can cope when the value contains single quotes, or double quotes, or even both types in the same string.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer. I understand all. I'll try it. If it works well, I'll mark this as an answer.

Comment: There is 1 problem here. I also put the parameter in the `match` attribute, but I can't write this: `<xsl:template match="$start">`. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @Forte_201092 XSLT 1.0 doesn't allow variable references in `match` expressions.  XSLT 2.0 does, but not in the way your example suggests you want (with the contents of `$start` being treated as a matching pattern).

Comment: Please see my edited part. I've tried some ways but it always has `<xsl:template name="start">` under my `<xsl:template match="myStart">`. The rest is OK. I don't know how to get rid of it.